# issue deploying to heroku

Tags: html, node.js, npm, heroku

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bwMP.png)I am trying to deploy my simple portfolio repo from vs code to heroku. I have github connected to heroku as well, but when I try to view the app I keep getting the standard error to search 'heroku logs --tail' and this is what keeps coming up:

```
2022-07-15T21:43:54.516758+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to 
starting
2022-07-15T21:43:56.285353+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm 
start`
2022-07-15T21:43:57.950177+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
2022-07-15T21:43:57.950324+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2022-07-15T21:43:57.950473+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
2022-07-15T21:43:57.950538+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your 
favorite packages
2022-07-15T21:43:57.950649+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages 
marked as favorites
2022-07-15T21:43:57.950736+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2022-07-15T21:43:57.950781+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
2022-07-15T21:43:57.950885+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!   npm run
2022-07-15T21:43:57.952469+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-07-15T21:43:57.952631+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can 
be found in:
2022-07-15T21:43:57.952685+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2022-07- 
15T21_43_57_911Z-debug-0.log
2022-07-15T21:43:58.077552+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-07-15T21:43:58.174557+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to 
crashed
2022-07-15T21:53:00.854021+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" 
method=GET path="/" host=mish-portfolio.herokuapp.com request_id=48b77be3-c391-4734- 
8532-4ce4787a4a21 fwd="71.47.185.245" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= 
protocol=https
2022-07-15T21:53:02.036670+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" 
method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=mish-portfolio.herokuapp.com request_id=f012031e- 
994d-4495-abaf-9ca1b125af47 fwd="71.47.185.245" dyno= connect= service= status=503 
bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: Could you post your `package.json`, especially the `scripts` section? Looks like you're missing the `start` script.

Comment: yes, the link is embedded at the top of the post now. thanks!